# HtmlAgilityPack set node InnerText 

Tags: c#, parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to replace inner text of HTML tags with another text.
I am using HtmlAgilityPack

 I use this code to extract all texts

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("some path")

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[normalize-space(.) != '']")) {
    // How to replace node.InnerText with some text ?
}
```

But InnerText is readonly. How can I replace texts with another text and save them to file ?

Comment: Element's inner text is a combination of all children tags inner text. Do you want to replace all children tags with a text node?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy I want to replace each element text with some text indeed I want to translate a website to another language.
I want to extract all text from a page then translate , replace and save .

Comment: It's odd that the XML documentation says that this property `Gets or Sets the text between the start and end tags of the object.` but then only provides a `get` method...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try code below. It select all nodes without children and filtered out script nodes. Maybe you need to add some additional filtering. In addition to your XPath expression this one also looking for leaf nodes and filter out text content of `<script>` tags.

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//text()[(normalize-space(.) != '') and not(parent::script) and not(*)]");
foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in nodes)
{
    htmlNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(HtmlTextNode.CreateNode(htmlNode.InnerText + "_translated"), htmlNode);
}
```

Comment: Very Good thanks. how can I overwrite translated html to previous file ?
I load Nodes from file/

Comment: If possible please just describe what's difference between my code XPath and yours ?

Comment: Just for extra clarification that the correct way to set text to a node is by replacing the `HtmlTextNode` with the new one that's created with `HtmlTextNode.CreateNode("text here...")`

Comment: I know this is an old question but you saved my life here, thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Strange, but I found that InnerHtml isn't readonly. And when I tried to set it like that

```
aElement.InnerHtml = "sometext";
```

the value of `InnerText` also changed to `"sometext"`

Comment: But you run the chance of changing the html tags also

Comment: InnerHtml is not readonly. InnerText is. The documentation seems wrong about InnerText being not readonly.

Comment: While `InnerHtml` supports get/set, in certain situations it does not always appear to actually change the document content. If you set it, and then look at the document's `OuterHtml`, the content is not always changed.

Comment: At moment of this comment (2021.01.04) it only supports get operations

Answer (score 7):

The `HtmlTextNode` class has a `Text` property<sup>*</sup> which works perfectly for this purpose.

Here's an example:

```
var textNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//text()").Cast<HtmlTextNode>();
foreach (var node in textNodes)
{
    node.Text = node.Text.Replace("foo", "bar");
}
```

And if we have an `HtmlNode` that we want to change its *direct* text, we can do something like the following:

```
HtmlNode node = //...
var textNode = (HtmlTextNode)node.SelectSingleNode("text()");
textNode.Text = "new text";
```

Or we can use `node.SelectNodes("text()")` in case it has more than one.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Not to be confused with the readonly `InnerText` property.</sub>