# Set textarea value with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack and it seems I cannot set the value of the text in a textarea in the same way as an input field:

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//textarea");
if (node != null)
{
    node.SetAttributeValue("value", record.Data);
}
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<textarea>` element doesn't have a `value` attribute. It's content is it's own text node:

```html
<textarea>
Some content
</textarea>
```

To access that, use the `.InnerHtml` property:

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//textarea");
if (node != null)
{
    node.InnerHtml = record.Data;
}
```

Comment: You can't set InnerText with HtmlAgilityPack, you can only get the value with that.

Comment: @realtek - `InnerHtml` [should be fine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9488079/3887516)

Comment: Oops, sorry... I was thinking InnerText! it works now thank you

Comment: @realtek not your fault, it *was* `InnerText` at first, but once you informed me of the problem, I corrected. (I don't have access to the HAP documentation, sorry)

Comment: :) Thanks for your help!