# Why HtmlAgilityPack adds some characters to my html

Tags: vb.net, textarea, html-agility-pack, cdata

Here is my code:

```
Dim input = "<div><textarea>something</div></textarea>"    
Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
doc.OptionOutputAsXml = True
doc.LoadHtml(Input)
Using writer As New StringWriter
    doc.Save(writer)
    Dim res = writer.ToString
End Using
```

and the value of 'res' is:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1255"?>
     <div>
         <textarea>
            //<![CDATA[
                something
            //]]>//
         </textarea>
     </div>"
```

> 

the result as html is: [My textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swZfk.png)

How can I prevent it ?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of it, the reason is implied by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33134873/1115360) to [Set textarea value with HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33134747/1115360):

> A <textarea> element doesn't have a value attribute. It's content is it's own text node:
>
> <textarea>
> Some content
> </textarea>

To simulate the same thing safely, HAP has to enclose the content in a `//<![CDATA[` section.

The [source code for HAP](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/master/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlNode.cs) has this comment for the relevant line(s):

```cs
// tags whose content may be anything
ElementsFlags.Add("textarea", HtmlElementFlag.CData);
```

So, you can't prevent it.